# Python 3 Keyboard simulation for a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard-events

How would I make the keyboard write Keyboardsimulationme using Keyboard simulation

```
myVarible = Keyboardsimulationme
```

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit more? You want it to look like the program is typing itself? Or you want to simulate certain key presses?

Comment: You need to use a module like pyautogui or something like it to simulate keyboard and mouse.